# Choose one in a duplicate/triplicate set conditionally in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame with approx. 500k lines (genetic markers). Some markers have the same CHR and STOP values (duplicates/triplicates) but all rows have unique SNP fields. I want to identify the duplicates markers (bases on CHR and STOP field) and then choose the marker (by SNP) with the lowest F_MISS value (last field). I have made it work by looping over the data frame numerous times (identify duplicates -> subset -> report the first row after sorting by F_MISS), but it is very time consuming. I am looking for a faster way to achieve the same. Sample below (see two bottom lines for duplicates where rs53565463 should be preferred over 1KG_10_12259383 because of lower F_MISS). Note that there are some triplicates in the list as well.

```
SNP               CHR  START  STOP    F_MISS
1KG_10_101715768  4      0 101715769  0.000e+00
1KG_10_102584498  5      0 102584499  4.967e-05
1KG_10_105796247  6      0 105796248  0.000e+00
1KG_10_1066786    2      0   1066787  9.935e-05
1KG_10_115662307  3      0 115662308  0.000e+00
1KG_10_12259383   10     0  12259384  7.100e-02
rs53565463        10     0  12259384  4.967e-05
...
```

**EDIT:**

As requested, the expected output is (note output is missing line 1KG_10_12259383 as rs53565463 is preferred because of lower F_MISS):

```
SNP               CHR  START  STOP    F_MISS
1KG_10_101715768  4      0 101715769  0.000e+00
1KG_10_102584498  5      0 102584499  4.967e-05
1KG_10_105796247  6      0 105796248  0.000e+00
1KG_10_1066786    2      0   1066787  9.935e-05
1KG_10_115662307  3      0 115662308  0.000e+00
rs53565463        10     0  12259384  4.967e-05
...
```

Comment: Could you post your existing loop?

Comment: Please add the expected output for this example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your data frame is `test`:

```
test <- test[order(test$CHR,test$STOP,test$F_MISS),]
test <- test[!duplicated(test[c("CHR","STOP")]),]
```

The first part orders the data frame so that the first record for each group of CHR and STOP will be the lowest F_MISS value. The next removes all rows that are duplicates of the first encountered combination of CHR and STOP.

The costly time aspect of this will probably be the ordering. You might consider using the `data.table` package to manipulate the data if you find that speed is an issue.

Comment: Thanks, this is both fast and works as expected. Even without data.table the ordering took a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` assuming you have your data in `df`:

```
res <- df %>% arrange(F_MISS) %>% filter(!duplicated(CHR, STOP))
```